# Why we have a core/thread limit on CPU?

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu, cpu-cores

In terms of programming multi-threaded environment, When we run multi-threaded application, CPU switches between threads. We can create and run thousands of threads in parallel.

I don't get then why we have a core/thread limit on a single CPU which not runs parallel in real case rather it just switches fast between threads to be run then why we have a like 8 core/16 thread CPU?

Comment: The 16-thread "limit" is the number of *concurrent* threads, on the *CPU*. It's not a limit on the number of threads a system can have, only how many can be executed simultaneously on the CPU.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That is the problem I think. Some answers says 16 thread is not actually working simultaneously. "CPU just switching between threads. To be executed simultaneously you need to have Multi-CPU"

Comment: @hellzone Are you mixing up CPU threads with programming/software multithreading ?

Comment: This is really how multi-tasking has worked since the very beginning in the 1960's: Multiple "threads" of execution are switched in an out by the operating system. The big difference between then and today is that this switching can be done more frequently with higher processor speeds, and that multiple cores (and possible "tricks" like Hyper-Threading) means that multiple threads can run simultaneously. And the difference between a "multi-CPU" system of yesterday, and the multi-core CPU's of today, is that the different physical CPU's have been merged into a single package.

Comment: @nos I think I am not. Can we run 16 "for loop" simultaneously on a 16 thread CPU? Does it finish 16 for loops at the same time with 16 different CPUs with single core?

Comment: @hellzone If you run it in 16 software threads, then yes you can run them  simultaneously. However a CPU thread shares many physical features with the core it is part of, so in many cases you will observe it as being slower than having 16 actual cores or 16 single core CPUs. (Note that a core normally have just 2 threads.). There's a limit, because these are physical entities - think of them more like single or multi-lane roads.

Comment: @nos Thanks for your answer. Now I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let's use an analogy**

"I run a hotel, where guests are switched between rooms. I can host hundreds of guests in parallel. One guest leaves a room, another enters it. If the rooms are full, guests wait in the lobby, but I quickly switch them, so every guest gets time in a room.

I don't get then why I have a room limit on my hotel building. I mean I fastly switch guests between rooms then why does my building have 8 rooms/16 beds?"

```
hotel = CPU
room = CPU core
bed = CPU thread
guest = software thread
```